# Can't retrieve Sharepoint lists using Simple.OData.Client. Getting "When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type"

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint, odata

I've googled the hell out of this, so any help will be massively appreciated.

Been around C# for awhile, new to OData.

Trying to access my sharepoint site data in my application via the OData feed. I can successfully get ProjectServer data, but when I try to access the sharepoint lists, it doesn't go so well.

C# Code

```
                ODataFeedAnnotations annotation = new ODataFeedAnnotations();
            var dataRaw = await context.FindEntriesAsync(query, annotation);
            List<IDictionary<string, object>> dataListRaw = dataRaw.ToList();
            List<SourceData> sourceData = new List<SourceData>();
            while (annotation.NextPageLink != null)
            {
                dataRaw = await context.FindEntriesAsync(annotation.NextPageLink.ToString(), annotation);
                dataListRaw.AddRange(dataRaw);
            }
            foreach (var item in dataListRaw)
            {
                sourceData.Add(ConvertDictionary(item));
            }
            return sourceData;
```

The query:

> http://csgdev5/PWA/A1/_api/lists/getbytitle('Risks')/items?$select=ID,Status,Category,DueDate,Author/Title,AssignedTo/Title&$expand=Author/Title,AssignedTo/Title

The error:

> A type named 'SP.Data.RisksListItem' could not be resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type.

I know I can get the FullName of the ListEntity by querying

> https:///_api/web/lists/getbytitle(‘’)?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName

But I wouldn't know what to do with that piece of information or how do I need to include that in my query to make it valid.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Anyone out there?... any help... come on!!!

Comment: Difficult to figure out without looking at your model, entity types and query definition. Can you open an issue at Simple.OData.Client GitHub site and provide that information there?